# A question on Finite Semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations, finite-semigroups

Why is it so, that a finite semigroup, say $(S, \circ)$ has $a^m=a^n$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m>n$ for $a\in S$?
Does it imply some sort of periodicity in the binary composition?

Comment: It follows from the pigeonhole principle: $\left\{a,a^2,\dots\right\}$ is a subset of $S$, hence it must be finite; this proves your claim.

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer??? I am having trouble reading it.

Comment: @Guy oh, I see. The first condition of being a binary operation is to be closed. Hence, all the repeated operations must lie within the set and their values may coincide after certain repetitions???

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

If no two of $a^1, a^2, a^3, \ldots$ were the same, then the semigroup would not be finite.

Answer (score -1):

You have that $a^{m-n}=e$ the identity, where $m-n>0$ is an integer. So that, there exist a minimal integer $k>0$ such that $a^k=e$. Then we have that the elements of the group are $\{a,a^2,\ldots,a^{k-1},a^k=e\}$.